# Is a complex inner product linear or conjugate linear in the first argument?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

For complex inner products:
According to Wikipedia its Linearity in the first argument: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space)

I have seen some place where it is defined conjugate linear in first factor.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kr3X1Pa9N3E&t=505s. Time 15:16 This is one reference only. i have seen other references also.

Am i missing something here or are they defining two different inner products? I really appreciate any help on clarifying this.

Comment: In quantum mechanics, linearity is usually defined in the 2nd argument. Mathematicians define linearity usually in the 1st argument.

Comment: Thanks Wuestenfux

Answer (score 2):

It's true that a complex inner product by one of the definitions will not be a complex inner product by the other. But the definition one uses is just a matter of convention: One can freely translate between the two conventions by mapping a complex inner product $(x, y) \mapsto \langle x , y \rangle$ to the complex inner product (with the opposite convention) $(x, y) \mapsto \langle y, x \rangle$.

Comment: Thanks Travis....

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found it useful.